# Amazon Aurora more than one Primary instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am trying to gather some information about Amazon new product Aurora and I was wondering If this product can have more than one primary instance for the same database?
Also is it possible to have more than one sharing?

I am referring to a multi-master model.

Comment: What is "more one sharing?"

Comment: AWS announced the preview availability of multi-master Aurora at re:Invent 2017 (2017-11-29).  Details are forthcoming.

Answer (score 4):

Currently Amazon Aurora is not really designed to support a multi-master model as it does not offer the auto_increment_offset and auto_increment_increment configuration options required for true active/active multi-master replication. Since every Aurora cluster can replicate to and from another Aurora cluster it is "theoretically" possible to setup an active/passive multi-master cluster manually. There is the potential to set up active/active if you can use primary keys that can be guaranteed unique across the cluster (ie. forget about auto-increment).

I typically don't recommend Active/Active multi-master due to the difficulty and risk associated with conflict resolution between the masters. Essentially, this makes MySQL an "eventually consistent" datastore, something that there are other, more effective solutions for.

For applications where uptime is paramount I typically recommend designing the application to continue operating in a degraded mode when it is able to read (replicas) but not write to the database. Then, a solid, tested, takeover/promotion strategy is needed to restore write capabilities (**[cough]** Amazon Aurora).